# 2d array out of bounds python

Tags: python, arrays, axis

I am trying to put values between two 2d string arrays.
atts is a dictionariy, have the correct values (I checked).
I have a loop, where the first and second interations work as expected, copying the arrays, but the third iteration (where key is '3rd' and its value is 301 which is bigger than the other two keys) doesn't work. it actually copies all as expected, but gives me a warning "index 301 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 301". it's really confusing, since the loop does the same for every key so why won't it work only for the third iteration?

```
for key in atts:

        cutTable = array(range( (atts[key]) * (len(Table[0])-1)), dtype='S10').reshape( (atts[key]),(len(Table[0])-1))
        m=0
        for i in range(len(Table)):                      
            if(Table[i][index_to_cut] == key):
                m+=1
                beenHere= False
                for k in range(len(Table[0])):
                     if (k==index_to_cut):
                       beenHere = True
                       continue
                     else:
                         if(beenHere):
                             cutTable[m-1][k-1] = Table[i][k]
                         else:
                             cutTable[m-1][k] = Table[i][k]
```

I printed dict atts for youall:

atts: { '2nd': 101, '1st':111, '3rd':301, 'crew':547)

I'm kinda stuck and I don't know how to solve this, if anyone knows I will be grateful..

Comment: Please add sample input and expected output.

Comment: Why do you have `(len(Table[0]))-1` in your array creation?

Comment: If you count from zero, `301` is the *302nd* item, and the size is `301`, so it's out of bounds.

Comment: I have len table-1 because I want to cut one column in my original matrix.. and my loop doesn't count from zero, and as I sid it WORKS for the first 2 iterations

Comment: input would be a 2d array(Table), and the output of every key is the cutTable which is only the rows where key exists in Table EXCEPT the column of this key (all keys in atts are in the same column in Table).. for atts I have showed, I need to have a new cutTable for every iteration. as I said, it doesn't work for the 3rd one

Comment: As @PeterWood said index 301 is the 302nd element which doesn't exist in an array of length 301.  Maybe you should start counting at zero because Python certainly does.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using Numpy correctly.  The strength of Numpy is avoiding slow loops in Python code and replacing them by internal loops of Numpy structures written in C, Fortran, or C++.

Even in pure Python a `for index in range(len(sequence))` just to use `index` for indexing `sequence` is an *anti pattern* because you can iterate over the elements of `sequence` directly. The variable `i` is unnecessary for instance. And when the index is needed in addition to the value at that index there's the `enumerate()` function.

Incrementing `m` is placed suboptimal.  If moved to the end of the `if` branch you don't need to subtract one for storing values in `cut_table`.

Pure Python could look like this (`np` is the `numpy` module):

```
for key, value in atts.iteritems():
    cut_table = np.zeros((value, len(table[0] - 1)), dtype='S10')
    j = 0
    for row in table:
        if row[index_to_cut] == key:
            for j, value in enumerate(row):
                cut_table[j][j - (j > index_to_cut)] = value
            j += 1
    assert j == value
```

But assuming the `cut_table` array is as long as there are `key` values in `table` you should really actually use Numpy to solve this, which may look like this:

```
for key, value in atts.iteritems():
    cut_table = np.delete(
        table[table[:, index_to_cut] == key], index_to_cut
    )
    assert len(cut_table) == value
```

This selects all rows from table where the value in column `index_to_cut` is equal to `key` and removes that very column.  Without any slow loop in Python code.